# about java script variable scope and facebook api

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am using facebook login api to get user information,  code can exceed correctly and FirstName can get from facebook api, but the first alert has correct value, the second value is still "". First I think it is because remote call time cause the second alert is before the first alert, after I using a delay function before second alert, also I can not get value in the second alert.

Part of code like below.

```
if (response.status === 'connected') {

        FirstName="";
        LastName="";
        FB.api('/me', function(response) {
            FirstName  = response.first_name;
            LastName  = response.last_name;
            Email  = response.email;
            alert(FirstName);
         });

         alert(FirstName);
```

}

Comment: Please read [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call) for an explanation of the problem (and solutions).

Answer (score 1):

FB.Api is asynchronies method, which will post/get to a remote server. 
The execution don’t wait for it to finish before your second “alert”
The only way you can be sure your FirstName is initialized, is using callbacks or MVVM pattern.
Here MVVM with knockout.js code:

```
var fbModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.FirstName = ko.observable("");

    self.FirstName.subscribe(function () {
        //DO what you want, first name just been changed from FB
    });

    self.load = function () {
        FB.api('/me', function (response) {
            self.FirstName(response.first_name); // WILL TRIGGER self.FirstName.subscribe
        });
    };

};
```

And don’t forget, applying this model is easy, I can give you some links if you want. (But just go and look on examples on their site)

Edit : callback version

```
var FirstName = ""; // Global


function callback(name) {
    //your name has been loaded
    FirstName = name; // Global is initialized
};



function load (callback) {
    FB.api('/me', function (response) {
        callback(response.first_name);
    });
};


//Now just call the load : 

load(callback);
```

Comment: Thank you for quick answer,this is good but I have to learn knockout a new thing to me, I would like using the way you said call back now.so if I just using the value in the response. I struggle and strange why can not get value outside.
Thanks again

Comment: Added callback version :)

Comment: Thanks for your beautiful explanation!

Comment: Thank you. If you need more help, just post a comment :)